# python как обрабатывать ошибки

Tags: python

у меня возникают разные ошибки сети:

```
SOCKSHTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.celebe.io', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=10)
```

```
SOCKSHTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.test.io', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /resource/v1/feeds/309026/like (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.contrib.socks.SOCKSHTTPSConnection object at 0x0000023BCF4BA8C0>: Failed to establish a new connection: 0x04: Host unreachable'))
```

Как я могу через Exceptions понять что это за ошибка и в зависимости от нее выполнять определенные действие?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так можно получить имя ошибки строкой:

```
try:
    #Your code here
except Exception as e:
    eName = e.__class__.__name__
    print(eName)
      
    if eName == 'ValueError':
        print('OMG! it is value error')
```